# How to play mp3 with powershell (simple)?

Tags: powershell, mp3

How do I play mp3 with Powershell?

What I tried:

```
powershell -c (New-Object Media.SoundPlayer "Track.mp3").Play();
```

Comment: Take a look on [powershell 'system.windows.media.mediaplayer' Register-ObjectEvent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924310) which explains how to play an entire MP3 list.

Answer (score 9):

You can play an mp3 from powershell, you just need to use

```
 system.windows.media.mediaplayer
```

instead of

```
 System.Media.SoundPlayer
```

It works in Windows 10

I followed a snipped from http://eddiejackson.net/wp/?p=9268

```
# Play a single file
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationCore
$mediaPlayer = New-Object system.windows.media.mediaplayer
$mediaPlayer.open('C:\sounds\bike.mp3')
$mediaPlayer.Play()
```

Work also perfectly on my side in Windows 11 ! Thanks a lot Guys !

Comment: Recommend accepting this answer.  It's the first answer that uses MP3 rather than WAV.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I just went through this so if anyone is interested in learning or knowing how to do this in a more simple manner use the following answer.

As long as you have a media player that has good command line switches such as VLC and other similar types of versatile players  (perhaps media player classic) you CAN make a one line command to run a MP3 file. Here is my example, enjoy! :)

```
& 'C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe' --qt-start-minimized --play-and-exit --qt-notification=0 "D:\SystemSettings\51Hz.mp3"
```

This would run 51Hz.mp3 file with neither notifications to take place nor any other user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

This works only for **wav** files:

```
$Song = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer
$Song.SoundLocation = "path\to\track.wav"
$Song.Play()
```

Comment: This works on its own when you run that, but if you have that in a script that you then invoke from another script (e.g. cmd) no sound plays.  I spent an hour trying to debug this only to realize the sound wasn't playing because the PS script exits and destroys the sound player object before the audio can play.

If you need to, make sure you call `PlaySync()` instead of `Play()`.  That way, the PS script waits until the audio has finished playing before exiting.

Answer (score 1):

From URL

```
$MediaPlayer = [Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer, Windows.Media, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]::New()
$MediaPlayer.Source = [Windows.Media.Core.MediaSource]::CreateFromUri('https://nyanpass.com/nyanpass.mp3')
$MediaPlayer.Play()
```

From File

```
$MediaPlayer = [Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer, Windows.Media, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]::New()
$MediaPlayer.Source = [Windows.Media.Core.MediaSource]::CreateFromUri('C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\nyanpass.mp3')
$MediaPlayer.Play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to just use the Invoke-Item cmdlet, it will open whatever Windows has set as the default handler for the file type.  When I used it on an mp3 file it opened Groove Music.  I'm sure if I installed winamp or mpc or whatever and set the default to that it would open in there instead.

Answer (score -1):

SoundPlayer can only play *.wav files. There is no easy 1 line way of playing mp3 files. However this can be done by writing a script using the MediaPlayer class.

Comment: however it is possible in 4 lines of code, I would still consider that simple

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
$Song = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer
$Song.SoundLocation = "path\to\track.mp3"
$Song.Play()
```

I guess you cannot pass the file location through new-object

Comment: Did you even try this, Musa? If so, you would get the following error:
Exception calling "Play" with "0" argument(s): "The file located at c:\temp\temp.mp3
is not a valid wave file."
At line:1 char:1
+ $Song.Play()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

Answer (score -1):

I can confirm this works:

`$player = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer "$env:windir\Media\notify.wav"
 $player.Play()`

Source: http://community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/playing-wav-files

Answer (score -2):

I recommend to just write, `Start-Process -FilePath "The/MP3/File/Path"`.