# Powershell script to play music

Tags: powershell, media

My goal is to create a script which when running, will make go into shared network drive and play all mp3 in the directory

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationCore
$mediaPlayer = New-Object system.windows.media.mediaplayer
$data = gci "\\srv\s$\music\"
foreach ($line in $data){
    $mediaPlayer.open("\\srv\s$\music\$line")
    $mediaPlayer.Play()
    
    
}
```

the script has no way to know if the mp3 is done, so what happens is that it "plays" for a milisecond and then moving forward to next item.
this will cause only the last file to be played.
is there a way i can make powershell "know" when an mp3 is dont playing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924310/powershell-system-windows-media-mediaplayer-register-objectevent

Comment: jeez i didnt not found that, thank you so much!